# Can't get this button to disable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I've been looking at this plugin here

http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2013/01/21/custom-styled-select-boxes/

In the instructions it says you can disable the list using this disable()

I added a button to the example 1 and have been trying to get the list to disable when the button is clicked to no avail.

I'm trying

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#start" ).click(function( ) {  
$("customSelect").disable("custom","disabled");
});

#start being the button id I am trying to use to disable the list
```

What am I doing wrong here? Using example1 template.

Comment: I think because the actual `<select>` is nested inside, because what you see is just layered sprites/divs/spans

Answer (score 0):

CustomSelect is either a class or a variable; you're using it as a html element which is incorrect. Either remove the quotes (if it's a variable)  or add a dot before it (if it's a class).

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation

> disable() Disables interactivity

`.disable()` does not take any parameters as you are trying to use, instead try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#start" ).click(function( ) {  
        $("customSelect").disable();
    });
});
```

in addition, your `customSelect` is not a valid selector unless you have an html element named customSelect, which I doubt.  More than likely its the ID of the element you want, in which case you should use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#start" ).click(function( ) {  
        $("#customSelect").disable();
    });
});
```

you also may want to consider storing a reference to the list when you intialize it, much like this example from [their docs:](http://www.roblaplaca.com/docs/custom-selectbox/)

```
<script>
    var sb = new SelectBox({
        selectbox: $("select.custom").eq(0)
    });

    sb.jumpToIndex(3);
    sb.disable();
</script>
```

then you can call .disable on that reference you stored... will definately work that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one......

$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```